# compile-time and run-time binding in method overloading and overriding

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

According to my understanding:

Private, final and static methods of a class follow compile time binding i.e. which method will be called is decided at compile time.

But, call to non-private instance method is decided at run-time.

This used to solve all my problems till now. But, I stuck in some problem where the above statements are not deriving the correct output.

Here is the code:

```
class Item
{
    Integer size;
    Item(Integer size)
    {
      this.size=size;
    }
    public boolean equals(Item item2) //not overriding the method of Object class
    {
        if(this==item2)
        return true;
        return this.size.equals(item2.size);
     }

  }

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Item itemA= new Item(10);
        Item itemB= new Item(10);
        Object itemC=itemA;
        System.out.println("|"+ itemA.equals(itemB) + "|" + itemC.equals(itemB)+ "|");
     }

}
```

Output it is giving: |true|false|

Output I expected: |true|true|

Here, the `equals` method of `class Item` is not overriding the `equals` method of `Object` but overloading is taking place because of different method signature of `equals` method.

Question:  In the call `itemC.equals(itemB)`, why the equals method of `Object` class is getting called.

According to me:  `itemC` is having object of `class Item` at run-time, therefore, `equals` of `Item class` should get called. At run-time there are two `equals` methods in `Item class`, one is its own and other one is inherited from `Object` class. So, `equals(Item)` should get called instead of `equals(Object)` because the call is for `equals(Item)`.

What exactly am I missing conceptually?

Comment: If only your expectation was correct, then Java would be a multiple-dispatch language and many things would be easier :) On the other hand, then a (multi)method would no longer logically belong to a single class.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: In the call itemC.equals(itemB), why the equals method of Object class is getting called.

Because the compile-time type of `itemC` is `Object`.

Overriding is performed at execution time based on the *actual* type of the target object, but *overloading* is performed at compile time based on the compile-time type of the target expression.

If you use `javap -c -v Test` you'll see the two method calls involved:

Constant pool:

```
...
#6 = Methodref #2.#32    //  Item.equals:(LItem;)Z
#7 = Methodref #16.#33   //  java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
...
```

Then the `main` method:

```
33: invokevirtual #6  // Method Item.equals:(LItem;)Z
...
40: invokevirtual #7  // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

So that shows the *signatures* for the methods that are being called. Which *implementation* of that signature is executed depends on the execution-time type. So if you override `equals(Object)` in `Item`, then that override will be called for `itemC.equals(itemA)`.

Comment: So are you saying that at compile time, the call `itemC.equals(itemB)` is getting resolved and binded to `equals` method of `Object` class. At compile time, `itemC` is of `Object` type and it doesn't know which object it will be storing at runtime then how overloading is taking place here for `itemC.equals`

Comment: @VikasMangal: The overloading *only* uses compile-time information. The type of `itemC` is `Object`; the type of `itemA` is `Item`, so the compiler looks for an appropriate `equals` method. `equals(Object)` is the only possibility here (there's an implicit conversion from `Item` to `Object`, so that method signature is valid), so that's what gets used.

Comment: You can compile Item and Test and run. Then you change Item.equals() to have an Object argument, compile only Item and run. And change the argument class back again to Item, compile only Item and run. What did the compiler decide at the compile time of Test??

Comment: @laune: I'm not sure what you mean - you're only changing `Item`, so that can't possibly change the code in `Test`... what behaviour are you seeing that surprises you?

Comment: @laune the compiler chose to call equals(Object) for `itemC.equals(itemB)` in compile time. If this method is later overridden by Item (if you make the change you suggest), at runtime equals(Object) of Item would be called instead of equals(Object) of Object.

Comment: "That can't possibly change the code in Test" is just the point. If (as you wrote) "the compiler looks for an appropriate equals method. equals(Object) is the only possibility...so that's what gets used." - However, the change of Item to have an equals( Object o) will indeed cause this method to be called. Nothing has been *decided* (!) at compile time of Test.

Comment: @laune: Yes, it has. The signature has been decided. You can run `javap` as shown in my answer to validate that. The *implementation* hasn't been decided, which is why the overridden implementation is called if you change `Item` to override `equals(Object)`.

Comment: Signature, OK. The paragraph "Overriding is performed at execution time based on the actual type of the target object, but overloading is performed at compile time based on the compile-time type of the target expression." creates the impression as if everything (including the actual method implementation being called) could be decided at compile time. But now it is clear enough.

Comment: @laune: I fail to see how "Overriding is performed at execution time based on the actual type of the target object" suggests that everything could be decided at compile time... a) it explicilty talks about *at execution time* and b) it talks about the actual type of the target object, which *can't* be known at compile-time.

Comment: @laune @Jon : Why the decision making is taking place at compile time. At compile time `itemC` is of `Object` type which has only `equals(Object)` present there.What I can interpret is, `itemC.equals(itemB)` has nothing to decide because no other equals method with different signature is present in Object.

Comment: @VikasMangal: That's simply how the language is specified: overload resolution is performed at compile-time; override resolution is performed at execution-time.

Comment: @JonSkeet If the decision is getting made between `equals(Object)` and `equals(Item)` at compile time, then `equals(Item)` should get decided because the call is `equals(itemB)` and `itemB` is of type `Item`.

Comment: @VikasMangal: But that's not what's available - `itemC` is of type `Object`, so the compiler can *only* consider `equals(Object)`. That's the only `equals` method it can "see" in `itemC`.

Comment: @JonSkeet So nothing to decide here at compile time since it can see only one method which is `equals(Object)` here. Am I right ?

Comment: @VikasMangal: Well, it goes through the same steps - but finds a candidate set of 1 method. It still needs to check that the method exists and is valid for the arguments, but yes - there's no need to decide which is the better candidate method.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is determined at compile time, not runtime. Therefore, `itemC.equals(itemB)` calls `equals` method of `Object`, since the type of `itemC` variable is `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from `jls` reg [`overloading`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9)

```
When a method is invoked (§15.12), the number of actual arguments (and any explicit type
arguments) and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the 
signature of the method that will be invoked (§15.12.2). If the method that is to be invoked is an 
instance method, the actual method to be invoked will be determined at run time, using dynamic method 
lookup (§15.12.4).
```

based on the above statement, `itemC.equals(itemB)` invokes the `equals` method of `Object` class, since at compile type `itemC` is `Object`